# "Ability to get global user IDs" API or functionality is being deprecated, is it the "id" value returned by the Graph API /me endpoint?

Tags: facebook

I work on a web application which calls the Graph API `/me` endpoint to get a few user fields after the user logs in via Facebook Login:

`https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/me?fields=picture.type(large),id,name,<...>`

I've recently received an email from Facebook saying:

> A list of the APIs you will no longer have access to are listed below. These APIs did not meet our thresholds for active usage and are being deprecated as a result. You also will receive a written notice of deprecated access to those APIs via mail over the coming days.
>
> APIs or functionality you might have accessed being deprecated:
>
> Ability to get global user IDs.
>
> We understand that this may require changes on your end and are here to help answer any questions you may have.

I'm trying to figure out if that "Ability to get global user IDs" corresponds to the "id" field I request to the `/me` endpoint?

I can't find a Facebook API documentation describing exactly what is the "id" field returned by the `/me` endpoint.

I replied to the Facebook but have not received any answer so far.

Comment: _“I can't find a Facebook API documentation describing exactly what is the "id" field returned by the /me endpoint.”_ - /me refers to the user object when used with a user access token, so of course you find that under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user#Reading

Comment: @04FS I like to understand how you found that "/me refers to the user object when used with a user access token". The only reference to /me I've found in this page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/ but that does explicitly says what you write. Do you have another documentation page? Thanks!

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#reading: _“The `/me` node is a special endpoint that translates to the user_id of the person (or the page_id of the Facebook Page) whose access token is currently being used to make the API calls.”_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id returned by the `/me` endpoint is a so called "App Scoped ID", there is no way to get the global id of a user anymore. Each user will get a different ID per App. If you want to identify users across different Apps: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/for-business/

Additional information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user#Reading